# Access to Google Calendar and Group Attendees for historical events via API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

This question is a bit different from the average "How do I access the members of a group invited to a calendar event". I have been using the AdminSDK/Directory API to do that and it works well.

My scenario is this:
I have 2 different calendar items 6 months apart (one in the past and one in the future).
The same google group has been invited to these calendar events.
In the past 3 months, membership of that group has changed.
When I look at the 2 events in GCal and I click the arrow next to the group name, the members are listed correctly, in that it knows a different set of group members were invited to the event in the past than the one in the future.
If I change the group members, it will be reflected on the calendar item in the future but not the one in the past. (as I would expect)

My question is, how do I access the historical attendee information of the past calendar event via the API (short of scouring everyone's personal calendars).

Comment: This is currently not possible AFAIK.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. :( Hopefully in V4

Answer (score -1):

This is accessible through the Calendar API, check on the get method of the Event resource (available in [this link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource)). The resource will expose the information of all attendees.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, using get(calID, eventID) only shows the group name as the attendee and not the members of that group at that time.